# Product of reaction between aluminium chloride and trimethylamine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Can anyone tell the product of the reaction between $\ce{AlCl3}$ (aluminium chloride) and $\ce{N(CH3)3}$ (trimethylamine)?

Comment: Have you read about Lewis acids and bases?

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few tips to get you started:

1. Lewis acids are electron pair acceptors; Lewis bases are electron pair donors.
2. This looks like a Lewis acid-base reaction. You mention that this *is* an acid-base reaction but there are no easily accessible protons in either reactant. Aluminum trichloride has **no** protons; trimethylamine has does have protons but these are $\ce{sp^3~C-H}$ type protons - which are extremely weak. Also, there is no path to stability; deprotonation of one of the methyl groups leaves a *localized* negative charge on a carbon.

There are other heuristics one can use. For example, note that aluminum trichloride has an electron-deficient aluminum atom (the Al doesn't have an octet). Acceptance of an electron pair *will* provide it with an octet. This heuristic works fairly well; consider boron trichloride for example. Boron is similarly electron-deficient. And boron trichloride is also a Lewis acid.

Also note that the amine has a lone pair. Keeping in mind that Lewis acid-base reactions are about the movement of electrons (rather than protons) then we might reasonably suspect this to be a Lewis acid-base reaction. Lone pairs generally indicate Lewis basicity, as these are generally available for donation to a Lewis acid. Delocalization of lone pairs can weaken the lone pair's Lewis basicity. Thus, the presence of a lone pair only serves as an indicator of Lewis basicity rather than the *strength* of Lewis basicity. And of course you can also donate bonding electrons rather than lone pairs (halogenation of ethene would be an example; the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond is broken and the electrons previously involved in that double bond are put into the antibonding orbital of some diatomic halogen)

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you then know how to find the VSEPR structure?

Comment: ALCL3NH3 Basically nitrogen donates a pair of electrons to form a dative bond, however i cant seem to deduce the central atom to find the VSEPR

Comment: @chemstudent you have to determine which atom the nitrogen donates its lone pair electrons to.

Comment: in this case aluminium, so do i use ALCL3 to determine VSEPR?

Comment: @chemstudent - if you want the structure of the end product, then you use the end product to determine structure.

Comment: i see, so in this case it will be a trigonal planar

Comment: @chemstudent are you sure the end product is trigonal planar? You can't use AlCl3 to determine the structure of the end product because the end product is *not* AlCl3.

Comment: well the end product is alcl3nh3, but how do i get the central atom?

Comment: @chemstudent you have to figure that out using your knowledge of Lewis acids and bases. Hint: the nitrogen lone pair goes into an empty p-orbital on Al in AlCl3.

Comment: tetrahedral it is then

Comment: @chemstudent - here's an example of how AlCl3 generally acts as a Lewis acid ... apply this generalization to your problem. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_OdZZiyNKEoU/SeH3Ma_Ul3I/AAAAAAAAAP0/qMIGqHkvrxc/s1600-h/Slide3.jpg

Comment: yeah its tetrahedral